# Spark __getnewargs__ error ... Method or([class java.lang.String]) does not exist

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to add a column to DataFrame depending on whether column value is in another column as follow:

```
df = df.withColumn('new_column', when(df['color']=='blue' | df['color']=='green', 'A').otherwise('WD'))
```

after running the code I obtain the following error:

```
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o59.or. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method or([class java.lang.String]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

what shall I do to overcome this issue?
I am using PySpark 2.3.0

Answer (score 21, accepted):

While using multiple conditions, each condition needs to be separated because of operator precedence.

```
df=df.withColumn('new_column',when((df['color']=='blue')|(df['color']=='green'),'A').otherwise('WD'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I discovered a similar problem with
`Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o166.and. Trace:` and the logs pointed to this line of my code:

`.when(df.line_item_line_item_type == 'Fee' & df.reservation_reservation_a_r_n != '', 0)`

adding sets of parenthesis around the statements to each side of the "&" solved the problem, like so:

`.when((df.line_item_line_item_type == 'Fee') & (df.reservation_reservation_a_r_n != ''), 0)`